# Which method should I use (fastest) to select element?

Tags: java, android, ios, selector, appium

Well there are a lot of different methods to select elements between Drivers. I would like to know which one is the fastest and the most suitable for native apps (iOS and Android) .

With the Appium Driver class there is :

```
findElementByAccessibilityId(String using)
```

With the Mobile class there is :

```
findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By by) //with ById/Xpath/Name/ClassName...
```

With Android and iOS driver class there are :

```
findElementByAndroidUIAutomator(String using)
findElementByIosUIAutomation(String using)
```

And using the RemoteWebDriver class there are :

```
findElementById();
findElementByXPath();
findElementById(); //css, className etc... -> WebElement which can be cast in mobileElement
```

So I'm guessing using `UIAutomator` and `UIAutomation` are faster but `selendroid` is needed for `Android 2.3+`.

How do you do and why? Can you provide me some examples for *findElementByAndroidUIAutomator(String using)* and *findElementByIosUIAutomation(String using)*

I saw there are some issues with XPath selectors. From my point of view using `findElement(By.name)` seems quite simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , just use UiAutomator, UiAutomation when you can (by default client-libs do it -for Id/Name etc...-, except for XPath which is slower, so use it when you haven't the choice.

See https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/158

*I use a function which takes in parameter the string selector and a custom enum for each type (id, xpath, even custom type like for Android parentIdChildEditText-still using UiAutomator-, etc...)* -> **don't do it !**

After years of experience, just use AccessibilityId if you can :
 which

- for ios is **name** in your appium xml source <=>
  accessibilityIdentifier for your ios dev
- for android is **contentDesc** <=> same appium source/dev identifier

Otherwise, the **simplest** selector for you (even xpath with text, still better to have custom test-id though). For these type of tests, selector performance is your last problem, maintenance and robustness are the main points.

Comment: Is this a how not to do it?

Answer (score 2):

> How do you do and why? Can you provide me some examples for findElementByAndroidUIAutomator(String using) and findElementByIosUIAutomation(String using)

```
AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver();
WebElement element = driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().resourceId(\"org.zwanoo.android.speedtest:id/upload\")");
```

Where "org.zwanoo.android.speedtest:id/upload" is the package id together with your element id. That is the way you can find it in your UiAutomatorviewer or Appium Inspector.

Comment: .findElementByAndroidUIAutomator appears on iOSDriver as well as AndroidDriver, classes that extent AppiumDriver and as a consequence: a newer and faster way to locate elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this sequentially:

`ID`, `Name`, `ClassName`, `XPath`. Whatever is available first use it. You can also ask your developers to add unique id for each element which is consider to be the best way.

Comment: Well thank you for your answer but it didn't really help me :p.